# Responsive Hover Box over Responsive Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I've been using a tutorial for making a hover box go over a set of images.
 
The article can be found [here](http://geekgirllife.com/place-text-over-images-on-hover-without-javascript/).

Got it working perfectly, except I want my images and the hover to be responsive to window size (just via width is fine), I've tried looking up how to do this. Seems like it might be a case of using % rather than a fixed value, but not experienced enough to know how to execute the markup. Even if I get the images to re-size the hover box doesn't re-size with them.

Is it possible to add something to the existing CSS to make this happen.

```css
ul.img-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.img-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}

span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

span.text-content span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="img-list">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
      <span class="text-content"><span>Text</span></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @media-query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use only width to keep image ratio.

you can use display:block for a and img, and use flex to center text.

not too sure about the responsive behavior you look for for, you can use a % width on li or a mix a % width + min-width and max-width.

example with % width set at 50% (and max/min width ) , it can be any other value and units.

```css
ul.img-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.img-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width:50%;
  max-width:100vh;
  min-width:60vh;
}
ul.img-list li a, ul.img-list li a img {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  }
span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display:flex;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

span.text-content span {
  margin:auto;
}

ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="img-list">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
      <span class="text-content"><span>Text</span></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is great bud, works a treat!! So easy when you know how :)

Comment: Hey, this worked great for me the other day. I'm using the same technique on something else. Only this time I want the text to be in the top right hand corner. I can't seem to get it right, even if I take out the `display: flex` and change the to  `text-align:right`

Comment: @Robin.83 just remove : `span.text-content span {
  margin:auto;
}` and then use justify-content on .text-content and/or eventually text-align. maybe you can make a new question :) Are you going to accept one of the aswers ?

Comment: Great, thank you again. Worked a treat. I've accepted your answer too. Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow. I'm still learning the etiquette!

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it like this, using pseudo elements to display the overlay content on the image. This method is fully responsive.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

/* Columns floated left */
.col-4 {
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Container to make absolute positioning easier on psuedo element */
.image_container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.image_container img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* Structure for ::before element */
#img_1::before,
#img_2::before,
#img_3::before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

/* Hover state for container to show ::before on mouseover */
.image_container:hover#img_1::before,
.image_container:hover#img_2::before,
.image_container:hover#img_3::before {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Text for ::before elements */
#img_1::before {
  content: 'Image Title 1';
}
#img_2::before {
  content: 'Image Title 2';
}
#img_3::before {
  content: 'Image Title 3';
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="image_container" id="img_1">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/B6PfiQ8QoSzmsZYOCkSB__DSC0530-1.jpg?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1004&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="image_container" id="img_2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1418985991508-e47386d96a71?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="image_container" id="img_3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476362555312-ab9e108a0b7e?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also set the images as a `background-image` for the `div` which would give you more control over the text in the overlay, if you needed it.

Comment: Thanks man, I've gone for the one below simply because it was a minor adjustment to the code I already had. This looks good too though!

Comment: @Robin.83 No problem! I'd recommend trying this method out when you have free time. The cool thing is how the spacing between the images (or the gutter in design speak) stays proportionate on as you resize the window. Anyway, good luck with your project!